# When to override and when to subscribe to delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I've noticed in C# I can handle events in a few different ways, but I'm unsure which one is best to use, look here:

```
this.Paint += Form1_Paint;

void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, 20), new Rectangle(50, 100, 50, 100));
}
```

or

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, 20), new Rectangle(50, 100, 50, 100));
}
```

Of course these both preform the same result, and the `OnPaint()` will normally (If I hadn't changed it) just invoke the `Form1_Paint` method through a delegate.

But which one of these is best to use?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way is to override the OnPaint method rather than registering to the `Paint` event. That way you aren't coupling a `delegate` to your `Paint` control.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx):

> Raising an event invokes the event handler through a delegate. For more information, see Handling and Raising Events.
>   The OnPaint method also enables derived classes to handle the event without attaching a delegate. This is the preferred technique for handling the event in a derived class.
>
> Notes to Inheritors:
>   When overriding OnPaint in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's OnPaint method so that registered delegates receive the event.

Answer (score 1):

These two approaches are **not** the same.

It is very possible to write code where the `OnPaint` method is called, but not to have the `Paint` method fire.

In fact, the code you have written in your question is exactly this situation.

Your code is missing the `base.OnPaint(e);` call that actually will fire the event:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, 20), new Rectangle(50, 100, 50, 100));
}
```

So you really should decide if your behaviour could be affected by choosing one over the other.

However, it 99.999% of all code that is properly written there is no distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, `OnPaint` overridden method is for myself(I mean the control or form itself). For example: If you want to change how your control look like you will do it in `OnPaint` overridden method.

`Paint` event is for others, by that I mean once you decided look of your control but it doesn't suit in some place, you want to make it little better you'll do it by subscribing `Paint` event.

In other words: `OnPaint` should be used when you're deciding a look of a **Type itself** where as `Paint` event should be used when you're deciding a look of an **Instance**.